# Simplifying a derivative

Tags: derivatives

I have been trying to calculate the simplified version of the penultimate term to the last one, but I honestly didn't find a way to do that.

[image]

So, I got to this, but how do I eliminate the denominator?

$$\frac{x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{x^2+y^2+x\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$

Thanks a ton for your help.

Comment: Hint:  Multiply numerator and denominator by $\sqrt {x^2+y^2}$.

Comment: Write 1 as $\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$

Comment: Thanks, which alternative is right now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the suggestions by lulu and Merlin explicit, write

\begin{align}
\frac{\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}+1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+x}
    & = \frac{\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+x} \\
    & = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}
\end{align}

where in the last step, we divide the highest-level numerator and denominator both by $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+x$.